# What does the Geneva Convention suggest in a situation where the military is deliberately operating from heavily populated areas?

Tags: international-law, geneva-convention

I don't think it's particularly controversial to claim that Hamas is operating various military infrastructure from within heavily populated areas in Gaza. In particular, they're using a hospital as their "[de-facto headquarters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Shifa_Hospital)".

What does the Geneva Convention suggest should be done in this case by the other side?

Comment: Well, the wiki article you link to does eventually say the claim is controversial. It only cites WaPo in the lede, but then there are other (Western) sources saying pretty much the opposite, based on eye-witness accounts by Westerners. So YMMV on the "headquarters" claim. There were probably some Hamas guys around at various points.

Comment: BTW, the WaPo article in question was written by former Jerusalem bureau chief, but he was writing that piece from London, so not exactly first-hand knowledge when he made the claim.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Article 19 of the Geneva Convention:

> The protection to which civilian hospitals are entitled shall not cease unless they are used to commit, outside their humanitarian duties, acts harmful to the enemy. Protection may, however, cease only after due warning has been given, naming, in all appropriate cases, a reasonable time limit, and after such warning has remained unheeded.

Accordingly, Israel should be allowed to just bomb those hospitals (or other seemingly civilian infrastructure) after warning to do so, and Hamas not complying to Israel's request to move their trouble out of there.

https://www.ohchr.org/en/instruments-mechanisms/instruments/geneva-convention-relative-protection-civilian-persons-time-war

Comment: Of course, the paragraph was designed for a war between effective governments, where it's assumed the government is responsible for the civilian population. No sane person would apply the same rules to an extremist group who fortified themselves in a hospital they took over under the threat of violence. "Hey, get out of that hospital" "Eh, no." "We're going to kill all the hostages!" "Have fun" :D

Comment: Both sides still have a general requirement to minimize civilian casualties (even if they're being used as human shields), so this may be achieved by giving warnings, but only if people are reasonably able to move and there's no better alternative. If one side is putting people in danger that doesn't give the other side carte blanche to kill them, despite what @RodolfoAP says.

Comment: @Luaan, "Took over under threat of violence" isn't accurate for 2 reasons; 1. Hamas has been operating in those hospitals for many years, so people going there should know exactly where they're going into. 2. Hamas has been elected by the people of Gaza to govern Gaza, in legitimate elections - althogh this is a solid fact, some people never get it, interesting why.

Comment: @Luaan Hamas *is* the effective government of the Gaza strip, democratically elected by the people of the Gaza strip. From a Western perspective they should be responsible for the wellbeing of the civilian population. But that is not the ballot on which they were elected, to say the least.

Comment: This appears to misinterpret the article in question. Article 19 says that hospitals are to be protected, except in the case that they are being used to commit "acts harmful to the enemy". The warning only applies after that threshold has been reached, and is an additional constraint on action against hospitals that are actively being used to commit "acts harmful to the enemy". This answer at very least doesn't establish that the first threshold has been cleared. Not all military uses are "acts harmful to the enemy", and even things like stockpiling weapons may be permitted under Article 19

Comment: Hamas's use of the hospital and other civilian infrastructure may rise to the level of "acts harmful to the enemy", but that needs to be demonstrated rather than assumed.

Comment: @Jacob3 That's a weird perspective. Hospital treatment is usually something that's forced on you by your health condition. Sometimes you have a meaningful choice of where to go and when... but these are people who don't really have much choice. And time is certainly not going to help - this is the "new" normal for them. All you can do is hope for the best.

Comment: @Luaan, So what situation is the Geneva Convention referring to? To a hospital full of healthy people?

Comment: Your concluding sentence would read much better in the correct temporal order. Israel should first provide a warning with a time limit to stop using the hospital as a military installation and if Hamas did not stop the military use then after the time limit they are allowed to treat it like a military installation and for example bomb it.

Comment: @quarague, Israel has been warning Hamas against using hospitals as their de facto headquarters, for many years already. This is long past due.